# Give 404 response on DELETE in restful Spring Boot Reactive Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am fairly new to Java and Spring Boot (coming from TypeScript) and
experimenting with a small restful CRUD Controller using the
reactive Spring Boot API.

There are many tutorials and examples out there but they all lack
proper response statuses, e.g. giving a 404 on DELETE when the
resource doesn't exist.

What I like to achieve is a DELETE handler which

- returns "204 No Content" if the resource existed and was deleted successfully
- returns "404 Not found" if the resource doesn't exist

A simple "I don't care about HTTP status" DELETE handler
looks like this:

```java
  @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
  public Mono<Void> deletePet(@PathVariable String id) {
    return petRepository.deleteById(id);
  }
```

This always gives status 200, even when there is no Pet for this ID.

I tried to use `petRepository.findById(id)` and `.defaultIfEmpty()`
in several ways to catch the 404 case, but without luck. E.g. with
this implementation I am getting always 204:

```java
  @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> deletePet(@PathVariable String id) {
    return petRepository.findById(id)
      .map(pet1 -> new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT))
      .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
      .flatMap(res -> {
        return petRepository.deleteById(id)
          .map(v -> new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT));
      });
  }
```

I think I understand why this isn't working, because after the .defaultIfEmpty()
the Mono isn't empty anymore and the .flatMap will have something to work
on (the 404 response) so the deleteById() is executed. This returns an (obviously)
non empty Mono as well, so the status turns into NO_CONTENT again.

But all my (many) attempts to change this failed so I hope anyone has the right
solution for this problem.

Thanks! :)

Comment: you should just need to move the `defaultIfEmpty` to be after `flatMap` to get the desired behaviour. In the case of `findById` returning an empty mono, you are returning a 404 `ResponseEntity` and then `flatMapping` it to a 204 `ResponseEntity`

Answer (score 1):

When `findById` returns an empty `Mono`, the code below will **not** executed either `map` or `flatMap` and will only return the value from `defaultIfEmpty`

```java
 @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> deletePet(@PathVariable String id) {
    return petRepository.findById(id)
      .map(pet1 -> new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT))
      .flatMap(res -> {
        return petRepository.deleteById(id)
          .map(v -> new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT));
      })
      .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
  }
```

Also, your understanding as to why this happens in your code snippet is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Michael. Unfortunately this does not work for me :(. I get 404 in both cases even when it deletes an existent Pet. Obviously the `defaultIsEmpty()` is triggered because `petRepository.deleteById()` (and in turn `flatMap()` too) returns an empty Mono.

Comment: Ah sorry, was not aware that `petRepository.deleteById()` was returning an empty Mono on success cases

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found a solution:

```java
  @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> deletePet(@PathVariable String id) {
    return petRepository.findById(id)
      .defaultIfEmpty(new Pet())
      .flatMap(pet -> {
        if (null == pet.id) {
          return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        }
        else {
          return petRepository.deleteById(id)
            .map(v -> new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT));
        }
      });
  }
```

Now an empty Pet object is created when `findById()` gives an empty
result using `defaultIfEmpty()`.

So the `flatMap()` gets either the Pet for the given ID or an empty
Pet. The latter is recognized by the fact that the id property is null
which is turned into a 404 response. In the other case the Pet is
deleted and 204 is returned. But note, that the `.map()` there isn't executed because of the empty `deleteById()` result. It's just necessary to satisfy the generic interface here. The 204 comes from the `@ResponseStatus` annotation.

So this is a possible solution - but it looks not very elegant to me (creating an empty Pet and having this no-op `deleteById().map()`).

If there is a better way to do this, please give your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as the above answers but I kept getting type errors trying them out so here's a more verbose approach:

```java
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deletePet(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
    log.info("Deleting pet with id: {}", id);
    Pet pet = petRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                    "Pet with the specified id is not found"));
    petRepository.delete(pet);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
```